# CDatabase::ExecuteSQL Bulk delete for Access Database

Tags: ms-access, mfc, odbc

I've an access database with more than 500,000 records and I want to delete records in bulk. I get a list of ids that I need to delete based on certain condition and this could be from 1 ~ 5000. Right now my code looks like this

```
 for ( i = 0  to 5000 )
 { 
    CDatabase.ExecuteSQL( Delete from table where id = ItemToDelete(i) ) 
 }
```

It takes almost 1 sec for each sql call.

Is there an option to do bulk delete or  Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Access is single Batch process only.  IE only one SQL statement allowed per batch.  If you want to do mass deletions, then put the ID's in the Where clause as a String then send it to Access to process.  Delete * From table where id in (.....).  Access is not an efficient DBMS at ALL.  It is meant really for one-person to operate in.

Comment: @GoldBishop 5000 IDs with IN is a very bad idea with any database. Access is not an DBMS, it generally uses Jet/ACE RDBMS, but not always. It is not for one person to operate in, it is multi-user. It can be highly efficient when used properly.

Comment: Bad idea maybe....solves the problem probably so.  Not to get into a debate but Access is a 1-5 person DBMS (which includes RDBMS), which is by perspective definition a 1 person system.

Comment: @bMathey...by chance, the application that is executing the statement against Access, could you do a RecordSet iteration?  It will allow you to perform a Cursor styled iteration.  As well, the text file with the ID's are they CSV'd or just CRLF delimitted?

Comment: I'm testing CRecordSet now. The ids are in an stl::list<int>

Comment: The most efficient way of deleting records is as a set. Using cursors is an anathema in any kind of SQL.

Comment: @GoldBishop the number of concurrent users in MS Access is 255 ( http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx), very much **not** a one person system.

Comment: Yeah tell that to 100% of my customers that complain when 5 or more users access the same database.  Dont use MS Best Practices and Product requirements as an argument cause 90% of MS documentation is flawed and inaccurate.  Your car is registered to go 150 MPH, can you actually get it to 150 MPH?

Comment: @Remou - "anathema" why not just say detested?  And FYI, Cursors have their place and use.  Especially if you are iterating through a loosely Relationed Database Schema.  And you right, 90% of those that use Cursors use them incorrectly.  But the other 10% can iterate through 1M records properly and efficiently in a faster time than most can perform a While Loop to iterate through the same data set with a bloated inside.

Comment: So, i tested the same code with another MS access database and it finished in almost ~15 min. In this case,  there are 20 sets of ids from ( 1 ~6000 ). I also, found that the database that I had initially was corrupted was compacted and fixed ( it had MsSysCompactErr table )

Comment: I'm not sure if that could be the issue in the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done Access in years, but I've had the same challenges. Instead of getting all the records that satisfy some condition, I would first try issuing a DELETE WHERE "some condition". It may still be slow, but would reduce the # of SQL invocations from 5000 to 1.

With such large #'s, a more extreme solution might be just dumping the whole table to a text file and writing a little program to reload it with only the ones you want. Probably not a good solution for a 1-time thing, but if you do this every month....

But in general, minimizing the # Sql calls is the best way to improve performance. Depending on the server, the delete operation may be a lot faster if the WHERE clause only includes primary key fields.

Comment: I'm confused.. I think I'm doing that.. may be my post was not clear.  in my ExecuteSQL(), I call a sql statement "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ID = i "  Is this right ?

Comment: I was thinking something more like "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ID IN (4,5,76,99)"; And just issuing that single call. And if it's literally ID equal to 0 through 5000, it could just be "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ID >= 0 AND ID <=5000"; But maybe the IDs were just examples.

Comment: Based on my condition the number of records that needs to be deleted may be 1 or 5000. I'm not sure if finding the records is taking time or the actual execution. I'll try your suggestion but first let me see if I can create a string like that.

Comment: @MarkStevens Yeah the solution is not very straight forward cause you have to logic to iterate through and then process.  Mark has the right methodology for approaching your solution though.

Answer (score 0):

That statement should read:

```
Delete from table where id between 1 and 5000
```

If you have a condition, for the most part you should be able to build a WHERE statement. Do not attempt to individually list 5000 ids with IN. You will run into every sort of limitation.

If it is not possible to distinguish criteria for deletion, individual ids can be listed in a table or a CSV, either will work with IN.

Comment: You miss the fact that the ID's are not between 1 & 5000, he will have between 1 & 5000 ID's to process.  And to discount the option of placing them into the IN statement is to cut off an option, albeit heavy but an option.  He has a query execution problem not a query design problem.

Comment: @GoldBishop I missed nothing. The code example says for i=0 to 5000 delete i, that is delete every row between 0 and 5000. He or she is running row by row rather than set.

Comment: that was `0 to 5000` ID's not ID's 0 to 5000.  Read it again although his example code is contradictory to his question body.